# JDBC and MS-Access null pointer

Tags: jdbc

JDBC null pointer error. while accessing the db. this is the query that i am executing.

```
"INSERT INTO paritosh ( customer, contactPerson, mobileNo, phoneNo, emailId, chairman, instituteName, totalEmployees, totalFaculty, totalStudents, totalClassroom, address, state, revenue, clientRate, acceptedRate, valuePerCard, rating, finderName, finderFee, comments ) VALUES ('kinley', 'adfa' , '232131' , '2323' , '@gmail' , 'adfadf' , 'zxc' ,100,11,1000,30, 'dfdfa' , 'Delhi' , 66000,60000,60000,600, 'Hot' , 'tyu' , 8, 'dfadfadfasdf');"
```

if i execute the code as sql query in the access the query runs fine.....

Please help

The JDBC code is as follows:

```
String insertq="INSERT INTO paritosh ( customer, contactPerson, mobileNo, phoneNo, emailId, chairman, instituteName, totalEmployees, totalFaculty, totalStudents, totalClassroom, address, state, revenue, clientRate, acceptedRate, valuePerCard, rating, finderName, finderFee, comments )";

String query=" VALUES ('"+customer+"', '"+contact+"' , '"+mobile+"' , '"+phone+"' , '"+email+"' , '"+chairman+"' , '"+institute+"' ,"+totalEmployees+","+totalFaculty+","+totalStudents+","+classroom+", '"+address+"' , '"+state+"' , "+revenue+","+clientRate+","+accepRate+","+valPercard+", '"+Rating+"' , '"+finderName+"' , "+finderFee+", '"+comment+"');";
     String build=insertq+query;

String query2="INSERT INTO paritosh ( customer, contactPerson, mobileNo, phoneNo, emailId, chairman, instituteName, totalEmployees, totalFaculty, totalStudents, totalClassroom, address, state, revenue, clientRate, acceptedRate, valuePerCard, rating, finderName, finderFee, comments ) VALUES ('virappan', 'dussal' , '4269887' , '12334567' , 'kumar@ril.com' , 'kumar' , 'RMIT' ,300,120,3000,150, 'adfad' , 'Delhi' , 400000,380000,390000,1500, 'Hot' , 'vineet' , 9, 'afddf');"; 

try{   
  s.execute(build);  
}
catch(SQLException se)
{   
  System.out.println("SQL eception");  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println(" error after running the query");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? Also, are you making sure that `s` is not null?

Answer (score 0):

- Looking at your code, I would suggest that you consider using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of the way you're doing it.
- Make sure that you have set up the connection before calling the `execute()` method. Note that this is only based on what you've provided. You should consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you want us to look at your overall code and help you out.